# need web page screenshot from different location

Tags: screenshot

i need a screen shot of my test page where i want to see how it will look like from different location. Actually the page will enable/disable few module based on location and i want to see how it will look like. I want tried with TOR project but it does not have option to choose the location. I need to screenshot from below location

australia
india
germany
us

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [www.browsershots.org](http://www.browsershots.org), the machines that take the screenshots are donated by people around the world. I don't think you can specify a country, but would give a general idea by randomly picking from the pot of countries.

Here are a list of the [screenshot factories and their locations](http://browsershots.org/factories)

Comment: Looks like the web site doesn't work any more

Comment: Good spot, I haven't used this in a very very long time, but it also looks like this page has an error: http://browsershots.org/factories it may be worthwhile contacting them in case it's fixable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy server to simulate the behaviour